# How to update TFS older version of SSIS package to currently deployed version?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, ssis

Using Visual Studio 2015, I checked an older version of an SSIS project into TFS.  Now I want to update that version in TFS to the one currently running in production.

I know how to get an *.ispac exported from the SSIS server, but I don't know how to update the existing SSIS project in TFS with it.

The desired result is to have the same version of the SSIS project in TFS as the one currently running in production.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Import .ispac into visual stuidio as a new project:

   - [Import an Integration Services Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-an-integration-services-project?view=sql-server-2014)
2. copy packages from the new project to the project under source control.